# how to convert from extractedInformation (using pytesseract.image_to_string) to dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this image:
[image]

I have extracted the text using pytesseract

```
# Use the image_to_string method to extract text from the image
extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = 'eng')
     

# Print the extract text
print(extractedInformation)
```

This is the output:

```
Moustafa
Engineer
Upwork Company

Ahmed
Teacher
School
```

How to convert the output to dataframe that has 3 columns cols = ["name","job","company"]?

I tried to convert extractedInformation to list by

```
list_word = extractedInformation.split('\n')
```

and this was the output:

```
['Moustafa',
 'Engineer',
 'Upwork Company',
 '',
 'Ahmed',
 'Teacher',
 'School',
 '\x0c']
```

but still couldn't convert it to dataframe with 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
import numpy as np

list_word = [s for s in extractedInformation.strip().split("\n") if s]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(list_word).reshape(-1, 3), columns=["name", "job", "company"]
)
```

Another variant (*without* [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)) :

```
data = [list_word[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(list_word), 3)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "job", "company"])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

       name       job         company
0  Moustafa  Engineer  Upwork Company
1     Ahmed   Teacher          School
```